# Simple command to test dependency download from maven central with the correct checksum?

Tags: maven

I am trying to prove that a particular dependency will download correctly from the maven central repo at http://central.maven.org/maven2/ with checksum checking.

I'm running a simple project with that one dependency in it

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

and even with --debug, I don't see that it is doing the checksum verification:

```
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://central.maven.org/maven2/
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://central.maven.org/maven2/ via myrepo:80 with username=fred, password=***
Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.4/elasticsearch-2.4.4.pom
Downloaded: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.4/elasticsearch-2.4.4.pom (19 KB at 6.6 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\2.4.4\_remote.repositories
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\2.4.4\elasticsearch-2.4.4.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=54, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=31, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=6, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=53, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=4450, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
```

I'm not sure that it had any effect, but I set up maven central as a repository and set `checksumPolicy` to fail:

```
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>real central</name>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: You can simply put the `<checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>` in your repository definition and Maven will automatically check the checksum and fails if it is wrong. The default is to produce a WARNING....Apart from that I would recommend to use a repository manager

Comment: I have the checksumPolicy. I just couldn't find where it was documented that it would produce a warning or error - found it now at https://maven.apache.org/settings.html